# How to display results of same column but have different values

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

Here I'm returning data from my database which have a title_heading column and it has a title column.

```
 id     title_heading    title
 
 1     HTML Tutorial     Home
 2     HTML Tutorial     Overview
 3     HTML References   Tags 
 4     HTML References   Events
```

but now I wanted to show the results like this in my view:

```
**HTML Tutorial**
   Home
   Overview

**HTML References** 
   Tags
   Events
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have two idea on this..
**first** normalize that table into two table..

heading : [id,name]
subTitle : [id, name, heading_id]

then you make oneToMany Relationship in laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

**second** you can use nested loop it and push it into array..

Comment: i think i can try the first one..
Thank You